# Android Apps can't access my SD Card storage BUT file managers can

Tags: applications, external-sd, sd-card, storage

Apps like Youtube, NetFlix, prime video do not have a "Store to SD Card" option. I have tried 3 different sd cards with my phone, formatted them but still, apps are unable to detect the sd card and do not have an option to download to external storage.
However, file managers and apps like vlc, album, and basically any media app can access and browse files stored in the sd card. How do I fix this?

I want youtube to store downloaded videos to sd card
same for NetFlix and prime video. 
I also tried uninstalling the apps and reinstalling them on my phone. I haven't found a fix yet.

My phone is running Android 8

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108888/discussion-on-question-by-deathrs-android-apps-cant-access-my-sd-card-storage-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a Factory Data Reset on my phone fixed the issue. Apps are able to write to SD Card. I would like to thank @IrfanLatif for helping me identify why this was happening. Ultimately i decided to factory reset my phone and it did fix the problem.